# Circular progress bar for a countdown timer publisher SwiftUI

Tags: timer, swiftui, progress-bar, combine

Below is my code for a countdown timer and circular progress bar.

I coded a function `makeProgressIncrement()` that determines
the progress per second from the timer total of `timeSelected`.

What is the best way to to update the `ProgressBar` so it increases with the countdown timer publisher?

Should I use an `onReceive` method?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var timer = TimerManager()
@State var progressValue : CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack{
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                
                ProgressBar(progress: self.$progressValue)
                    .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300)
                    .padding(40.0)
              
                VStack{
                    
                    Image(systemName: timer.isRunning ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .onTapGesture{
                            timer.isRunning ? timer.pause() : timer.start()
                        }
                }
            }

            Text(timer.timerString)
                .onAppear {
                    if timer.isRunning {
                        timer.stop()
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 100)
            
            
            Image(systemName: "stop.fill")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .onTapGesture{
                    timer.stop()


                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**ProgressBar**

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 20.0)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(self.progress, 1.0)))
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
                .animation(.linear)
            
        }
    }
}
```

**TimerManager**

```
class TimerManager: ObservableObject {
    
    /// Is the timer running?
    @Published private(set) var isRunning = false
    
    /// String to show in UI
    @Published private(set) var timerString = ""
    
    /// Timer subscription to receive publisher
    private var timer: AnyCancellable?
    
    /// Time that we're counting from & store it when app is in background
    private var startTime: Date? { didSet { saveStartTime() } }
    
    var timeSelected: Double = 30
    var timeRemaining: Double = 0
    var timePaused: Date = Date()
    var progressIncrement: Double = 0
    
    init() {
        startTime = fetchStartTime()
        
        if startTime != nil {
            start()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Public Interface

extension TimerManager {

    func start() {
     
        timer?.cancel()               
        
        if startTime == nil {
            startTime = Date()
        }
        
        timerString = ""
        
        timer = Timer
            .publish(every: 0, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                guard
                    let self = self,
                    let startTime = self.startTime
                else { return }
                
                let now = Date()
                let elapsedTime = now.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
                      
                self.timeRemaining = self.timeSelected - elapsedTime
                                    
                guard self.timeRemaining > 0 else {
                    self.stop()
                    return
                }
                self.timerString = String(format: "%0.1f", self.timeRemaining)
            }
        isRunning = true
    }
    
    func stop() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timeSelected = 300
        timer = nil
        startTime = nil
        isRunning = false
        timerString = " "
    }
    
    func pause() {
        timeSelected = timeRemaining
        timer?.cancel()
        startTime = nil
        timer = nil
        isRunning = false
    }
    
    func makeProgressIncrement() -> CGFloat{
        
        progressIncrement = 1 / timeSelected
        
        return CGFloat(progressIncrement)
        
    }        
}

private extension TimerManager {

    func saveStartTime() {
        if let startTime = startTime {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(startTime, forKey: "startTime")
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "startTime")
        }
    }
    
    func fetchStartTime() -> Date? {
        UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "startTime") as? Date
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `.onReceive`. Or, you could make it a computed property of the `TimerManager` class and use it directly, for example, something like this: `self.$timer. progressIncrement`

Comment: @NewDev Tried `.onReceive` but I'm getting an error that `TimerManager` doesn't conform to 'Publisher'. Since `progressIncrement` is in the class, how would I use it directly to update the ProgressBar `progressValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a computed property in `TimeManager` that calculates the progress:

```
extension TimerManager {
  var progress: CGFloat {
     return CGFloat(timeRemaining / timeSelected)
  }
}
```

But you also need a trigger for the observers to tell them that it's changed.

Since this value depends on a `timeRemaining` property, which is `@Published`, it would work because the observing object will notice a change and ask for the computed value again (which would also change).

Alternatively, you can call `self.objectWillChange.send()` inside the `.sink` to notify that an object will change, and that will accomplish the same thing.

Once you have that, you can just refer to it directly in your views:

```
ProgressBar(progress: self.timer.progress)
```

(and change `ProgressBar` so that its `.progress` property isn't a binding.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get the following error using the computed property: _Cannot assign to property: 'progress' is a get-only property_ . I tried a get / set but the progress bar still does not update correctly every second the timer is counting down.

Comment: what exactly are you assigning? The idea is that this property is computed from `timeSelected`, so you shouldn't be assigning anything to it - just set `timeSelected`

Comment: `ProgressBar(progress: self.$timer.progress)` throws the error while trying to pass the timer.progress property

Comment: Oh, I see. `ProgressBar` accepts it as a binding. Why, though? Unless I'm missing something, It should just be a regular parameter. (I changed my answer)

Comment: If I change the variable in the `ProgressBar` struct to non-binding the error disappears but the progress bar is still not synchronized with the timer. It fires only once when the starts `timer.start()`.

Comment: Ah, right. `timeSelected` isn't actually being updated. Come to think of it, why was progress equal to `1/timeSelected`? If progress is a fraction, then shouldn't it be `timeRemaining/timeSelected`? I changed my answer to that, so it should work. But the basic idea is that the computed property needs to rely on a `@Published` property to be updated. Alternatively, use `self.objectWillChange.send()` inside the timer's `sink`.

Comment: Your code works, thank you. I was calculating the initial increment to subtract per second stead of constantly calculating the current progress.